# Interchange two words with regex

Tags: regex

Suppose we want to convert from

> I have cat, cat and cat and she has dog, dog and dog.

to

> I have dog, dog and dog and she has cat, cat and cat.

Of course it can be done with multiple regex:

```
s/cat/monkey/g
s/dog/cat/g
s/monkey/dog/g
```

So the question is whether it can be done with **one** regex.

Comment: Many regex engines support a callback for replaces, which would make that easy.

Comment: What tool/language are you using? You can even do it with plain regex in some of them.

Comment: With one regex alone in a single operation, unlikely.

Comment: @DJDavid98: I know 2 regex engines that can do it in 1 operation.

Comment: @stribizhev vim, sed or perl. I assume the problem still falls in the regex domain but needs an elegant (possibly tool/language specific) solution since it appears very often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Perl solution

You can define a hash with the replacements, and use a regex with `e` modifier that will let you pass the backreference to the code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
%data = ('cat', 'dog', 'dog', 'cat');
$x = "I have cat, cat and cat and she has dog, dog and dog.";
$x =~ s/\b(dog|cat)\b/$data{$1}/eg;
print $x;
```

Output of the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/vzMseq): `I have dog, dog and dog and she has cat, cat and cat.`

## Original answer using Notepad++

If you plan to use Notepad++, you can make use of named capture groups with a conditional replacement pattern:

Find What: `\b(?<o1>dog)|(?<o2>cat)\b`

Replace With: `(?{o1}cat:dog)`

[image]

The regex will only match whole words `dog` or `cat`, and depending on the group matched, will use the appropriate replacement.

This possible due to Boost regex library used in Notepad++.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you would do it in .NET:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(cat|dog)");
var text = regex.Replace(template,
            match => match.Value=="cat"?"dog":"cat");
```

Comment: And this pattern will replace `cat` in `catastrophe`.

Comment: @stribizhev So would OPs example - I was assuming they're aware of this simplification as it's not really relevant to the underlying problem/question...

Comment: @JamesThorpe You are correct, thanks.  Updated answer.

Comment: He could use `\b(cat|dog)\b` if he only wanted entire words.